# problem with long table

Tags: longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}            
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \centering


\begin{longtable}{\textwidth}{|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|}
\hline
\textbf{Mobility  Model} &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
        \cline{2-8}
        & \textbf{Basic Description} 
        & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} 
        & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} 
        & \textbf{Safety parameters} 
        & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} 
        & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
\hline

\end{longtable}%

\end{landscape}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: table is not in proper shape as row and column are not spanning

Comment: Without using an appropriate package that combines the features of `longtable` and `tabularx` you can not use `X` type (or derived column types) in a `longtable`. Possible packages for this task are [ltxtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) and [ltablex](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex)

Comment: They're not spanning what?

Comment: "row and column are not spanning"  is not exactly clear. Please clarify your objective. E.g., are you trying to get a table that's longer than one page?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution using the `ltablex` package that combines the features of `tabularx` with `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}            
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|}
\hline
\textbf{Mobility  Model} &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
        \cline{2-8}
        & \textbf{Basic Description} 
        & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} 
        & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} 
        & \textbf{Safety parameters} 
        & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} 
        & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
\hline
\endhead
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\

\end{tabularx}%

\end{landscape}%
\end{document}
```

Please note that all the `1\\1\\1\\` are just added to show the page breaking behaviour of the table. I have also added `\endhead` in order to repeat the column headers on all following pages.

Answer (score 4):

I propose to load the `xltabular` package and use its eponymous environment, which combines the possibilities of `longtable` and `tabularx`. Also, note that in the `landscape` environment, for a full width table, you have to use `\linewidth` or `\textheight`, but not `\textwidth`. Last, you can gain some space in cells loading `geometry`, which has more sensible margins if you don't use margin notes, setting `\tabcolsep` to a lower value (6 pt by default, I set it to 3) and using a smaller fontsize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
 \centering
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|*{8}{X|}}
\hline
\multirow{8.45}{=}{\textbf{Mobility Model} }& \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}} \\
        \cline{2-8}
        & \textbf{Basic Description}
        & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs}
        & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates\smallskip}
        & \textbf{Safety parameters}
        & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint}
        & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}%
\end{landscape}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i am having error "Undefined control sequence \addparagraphcolumntypes".

Comment: Oops! Sorry, remove that line. It's a remnant of another trial, and I removed the package which defines this command.

Comment: thanks sir, this is what i need